# Python email sending script works for some sender/receiver combination but not others

Tags: python, authentication, email, credentials

I wrote Python code that sends email message(s)
I wanted the code to handle any sender / receiver combination.
For this script, I created a 'test' Google user whose email address I tried to use in the script.
I had some issues initially and someone indicated that due to some changes in recent authentication requirement, an application password was required.
So, I created one.
Now, the code is working with that user as the sender but does not work with other 'sender' users.
I run the code from my (windows 10) desktop.

The error I am getting:
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.
Generated in:
line 662, in auth raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
What is going on? Is the Application password be unique for each sender / receiver?
I am using the same application (? what IS the application ? - python?, my script?)

Thanks

Details are described above.
I tried multiple sender/receiver combinations

Comment: The "other sender users" are different Google accounts? Yes, you need the application passwords for all those accounts.

Comment: Thanks for the blazing fast response ... 
Will a yahoo "sender user" (I created and have a Yahoo account)  work?
Should I / Can I created an App password for such user?

Comment: `app password` you need only when you use `Google Mail`. Other portals (like `Yahoo Mail`) may have own rules and it may need normal password (ie. for `yahoo sender`). But if you want to use `yahoo sender` then you have to configure `SMTP` to connect to `Yahoo Mail Server`, not to `Google Mail Server`

Comment: Sending an email through Python's smtplib is basically an automated way of logging-in into the email platform (Google, Yahoo, etc.), inputting your credentials (ex. username, password), composing your email, then clicking on "send". If you think of it that way, then for each "sender", you need to provide its own credentials and route it through the correct email servers. In other words, in your example, you cannot use your Yahoo account as a "sender" to send an email through Google's email servers, or you cannot use someone else's account as a "sender" without putting their username/password.

Comment: Usually, automated email sending applications have a fixed set of accounts that you use as a "sender", configured for a particular email provider/server (ex. GMail, etc), and it's only the receiver/recipient (and email body of course) that changes.